# How to remove parentheses only around single words in a string

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have a string like this:

```
s = '((Xyz_lk) some stuff (XYZ_l)) (and even more stuff (XyZ))'
```

I would like to remove the parentheses only around single words so that I obtain:

```
'(Xyz_lk some stuff XYZ_l) (and even more stuff XyZ)'
```

How would I do this in Python? So far I only managed to remove them along with the text by using

```
re.sub('\(\w+\)', '', s)
```

which gives

```
'( some stuff ) (and even more stuff )'
```

How can I only remove the parentheses and keep the text inside them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
re.sub(r'\((\w+)\)',r'\1',s)
```

Use `\1` or backreferencing.

Comment: Thanks, works fine! Kasra uses \b in his answer.  Any reason why you don't use it? I upvote your answer as well as it is working fine.

Comment: @Cleb we dont need it as `\b` is word boundary and `\w` will only match words and we have `()` around it.So we dont need it at all

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. Would you mind elaborating on how the \1 works? Have not much experience in this topic...

Comment: @Cleb `\1` stores whatever is inside `()`.Here inside `()` we have `\w+`.So the word gets stored in `\1`.Now you replace whole thing by `\1`.So the word gets replaced.

Comment: You were slightly faster, so I accept yours. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

You can use back-reference (actually in `sub` function they called group reference numbers):

```
>>> s='((Xyz_lk) some stuff (XYZ_l)) (and even more stuff (XyZ))'
>>> 
>>> re.sub(r'\((\w+)\)',r'\1',s)
'(Xyz_lk some stuff XYZ_l) (and even more stuff XyZ)'
>>>
```

For more info read the following explanation about backreferences from http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html:

> Backreferences match the same text as previously matched by a capturing group. Suppose you want to match a pair of opening and closing HTML tags, and the text in between. By putting the opening tag into a backreference, we can reuse the name of the tag for the closing tag. Here's how: `<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>.*?</\1>`. This regex contains only one pair of parentheses, which capture the string matched by `[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*`. This is the opening HTML tag. (Since HTML tags are case insensitive, this regex requires case insensitive matching.) The backreference `\1` (backslash one) references the first capturing group. `\1` matches the exact same text that was matched by the first capturing group. The `/` before it is a literal character. It is simply the forward slash in the closing HTML tag that we are trying to match.

Comment: Thanks! Works fine. Why are the \b needed? In vks' answer they are not included. Any specific reason for that? I upvote the answer since it answers the question.

Comment: Because of the nature of `\w`, boundaries are redundant, i.e. the effect will be the same whether boundaries are included in the regex or not. However, it's good to use them in general. @Cleb, from `pydoc re`: `\b — Matches the empty string, but only at the start or end of a word.`

Comment: @Cleb In short, word boundaries forced your regex engine to match only concatenated characters which have been made by the regex within the in this case \w read more http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html werkritter is right you don't need word boundary in this case

Comment: If it is redundant, there is no reason to use it. Most engines don't optimize them out.

Comment: @Kasra: Ok, thanks for the clarification. Would you mind elaborating on how the \1 works? Have not much experience in this topic...

Comment: @Kasra: Great, thanks! I upvoted yours but will accept vks' answer since he was slightly faster. Thanks for all your help!